# Direct2D desktop window class template based on ATL's CWindowImpl

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, atl, direct2d

Kenny Kerr in his tutorials ([part1](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/direct2d-fundamentals), [part2](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/direct2d-fundamentals-part2)) on Direct2D shows how to make a simple 2D animated clock and uses the following classes hierarchy:

```
//Desktop window class based on ATL's CWindowImpl
template <typename T> struct DesktopWindow :
CWindowImpl<DesktopWindow<T>, CWindow, CWinTraits<WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE>>
{
    // code here, including:
    void Run() {}
};

//ClockSample class which further extends DesktopWindow
template <typename T> struct ClockSample : T
{
    //code here
};

//SampleWindow class which is empty and is needed, as far as I understand,
//to, so to speak, "untemplate" ClockSample template
struct SampleWindow : ClockSample<DesktopWindow<SampleWindow>>
{
    //empty
};

//main function
int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    SampleWindow window;
    window.Run();
}
```

I didn't include actual code, because it's huge and is irrelevant for the question.

`struct SampleWindow : ClockSample<DesktopWindow<SampleWindow>>` - I have difficulties in understanding which class inherits from which and what here? SampleWindow inherits from ClockSample and then there is again SampleWindow which looks like a circular reference to me? I would be glad if anybody could explain in simple words what actually is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SampleWindow` inherits from `ClockSample` ("untemplates"), which in turn is derived from `DesktopWindow`, which in its turn is derived from ATL's `CWindowImpl` (which is further having `CWindow` as a base class; `CWindow` is a thin wrapper over `HWND` window handle).

Having `SampleWindow` as template argument allows to "downcast" in code to descendant class and call overridden methods without having them virtual. This approach is massively used in ATL, in particular.

For example:

```
template <typename T> struct DesktopWindow :
CWindowImpl<DesktopWindow<T>, CWindow, CWinTraits<WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE>>
{
    // code here, including:
    void Run()
    {
      T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this); // T = SampleWindow
      pT->InternalRun();
    }
};

struct SampleWindow : ClockSample<DesktopWindow<SampleWindow>>
{
    VOID InternalRun()
    {
      // So we eventually reach here
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way, isn't it actually "downcast"?